# Microsoft Flow Add Outlook attachment to VSTS Work Item

Tags: outlook, azure-devops, power-automate, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to get an [Outlook attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/outlook/#clientreceivefileattachment) uploaded to VSTS (using the [Send an HTTP request to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/#send-an-http-request-to-vsts) action). I have everything else working. Including added the attachment to the ticket, but the "uploaded" file is nothing. I've tried every combination of expression to convert the attachment content, no luck. I'm sure I'm just missing some intermediary step.

Here's the "Create Attachment" step I'm using to upload the image before updating the Work item. (The **Content** in the *Body* field was just one attempt. From the linked Outlook attachment doc, its type is "byte".)
[image]

And here's the work item, with said attachment, but there is no file content.
[image]

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The size should not be 0K. I suspect that you missed "attributes" property in the request body when link the attachment to the workitem.

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT Adding the "attributes" property solved the file size issue, but I still cannot save the outlook attachment as the actual type of file it is. For example, I'm testing with a `.jpg` file, but after creating the attachment in VSTS it's just a txt file with the base64 string content and a .jpg extension.

Comment: That's related to Flow part. If you check the input from Flow, you can see that it is sending base64 string to VSTS.

Answer (score -1):

You could check VSTS rest api of [Uploads an attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/attachments/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) here:

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName={fileName}&uploadType={uploadType}&areaPath={areaPath}&api-version=4.1
```

If you want to upload a text file, the api is as below:

```
POST https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/attachments?fileName=textAsFileAttachment.txt&api-version=4.1

"User text content to upload"
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing, I can post to the endpoint fine. The issue is that I cannot translate the file from the outlook attachment trigger output to a format that the VSTS endpoint will use to correctly create the file. The attachments can be of any type. Look at the two links I have in my question. It's more of a Flow question than a VSTS API question.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue which I am struggling from past 3 weeks. Couldn't get the attachment working. Any input will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.